# Redirect user in Login Form if the user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, c#, php, web-development-server

I am beginner in web development, I really wanted to develop my first dashboard application using a downloaded template of bootstrap and html5. I have already created a logged in code for the template and I want to have a what do we call routing or in php is session. I have a php code that will not allow the user to redirect to any page without logging in its account for security purposes of the data inside the application.

**PHP**

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();
   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   $temparray = array();

      $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select user_id,username,fullname from user where username = '$user_check'");
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$ses_sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($row == 1 ){   
                array_push($temparray, $row); //save your data into array
                echo json_encode($temparray);
        } else {
                echo header("Location: ../pages-login.html");
        }
?>
```

This php code will redirect you to login page if you will type path of the application in address bar of chrome. for example.

If I only put this `http://localhost:64730/Static_Full_Version/index.html` in the address bar without logging in. it will redirect you if you don't have a session. and it will be vulnerable on security attacks.

I want to know how can i possibly implement the php code in above in javascript, using c# because the platform I am using is visual studio.

If it's possible, can someone teach me to the right path of the coding for me to solve the security attacks?

The main question is, how can i have a session just like in php if the user is not logged in and redirect him/her to logged in form and cannot access the website??

Any help will much be appreciated. Thanks in Advance. Regards.

Comment: `if ($row == 1 )` - What are you trying to check here? `$row` will be an array, not an integer.

Comment: _"I want to know how can i possibly implement the php code in above in javascript, using c# "_ - So do you want it in javascipt or C#? Those are two completely different languages.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , Sir the code above is just sample for what I am trying to do. Actually, it is not the real code for what I am trying to develop. Just a sample code for what i am trying to do in javascript and c# in visual studio

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in Javascript sir

Comment: You can't write the above code using JS. JS doesn't have access to MySQL and can't make any database requests (unless you're talking about building it in node.js). However, your question is off-topic. SO isn't a code conversion site. You need to make some attempts and try something yourself first. If you then get stuck on something _specific_ with your _existing_ code, come back and we can help you.

Comment: _"Actually, it is not the real code for what I am trying to develop"_ - I don't see the point in asking about sample code. You would still need to rewrite it to be correct later. Why not just post the actual code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , Is that so sir.Ok sir. I just delete this thread. Thanks By the way. I thought someone can help me with it..

Comment: You can have this with the new ASP.NET Core. Check docs and you will see how easy it is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , I don't really know how to do that sir. Sessioning in javascript. Because i am beginner in web development. that's why. maybe I will push my self to do it so. Thanks again sir.

Comment: You should start simple and work your way up. SO is the wrong place for these kind of questions since we require that you've made a lot of research and made some attempts before asking here.